# HTTPPost to JSON in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, utf-8, http-post

I am doing an HTTP Post request in Javascript in order to update a JSON file.

```
function updateJson(dataNew){
  var stringData = JSON.stringify(dataNew);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: 'update.php',
    data: {stringData},
    success : function(d){
       alert('done');}
    })
}
```

Then in PHP:

```
<?php
  $a = json_encode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  file_put_contents('newData.json', $a);
?>
```

I want JSON data in the JSON file however, the json file only includes a single string which is similar to the request payload of the http post. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to pass a key/value pair in the data object, and leave the contentType attribute as default (remove it), like:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: {myjson: stringData},
    ...
);
```

Then in PHP you should read the posted data and get that *myjson* element, without encoding it again, as it is already JSON:

```
<?php
  $a = $_POST['myjson'];
  file_put_contents('newData.json', $a);        
?>
```

Comment: I have tried it, but now the json file is empty. Which means that the $_POST['myjson'] is empty aswell?

Comment: Have you debugged? You could put `var_dump($_POST)` at the start of your PHP to see what you are actually getting. For that you better change the `alert("done")` to `alert(d)` so you get an idea what PHP is outputting.

Comment: "Undefined index: myjson in update.php" That's probably the problem, but it's weird as my post request containts: `data: {myjson: stringData},`

Comment: Could you just put `var_dump($_POST);` in your php file and put all the rest in comments for the moment, and see what output you get (in the alert)?

Comment: `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>`

Comment: Ok, could you remove the contentType argument in your ajax call and see what happens?